# Regex for a permutation of exactly 7 digits and 2 hyphens, without 2 consecutive hyphens

Tags: regex

I a looking for a Regex to match a string which should:

- start with a digit
- 'in-between' have a permutation of exactly 7 digits and 2 hyphens, without 2 consecutive hyphens
- end with a sequence of digit, hyphen, digit

Match:

- 01-234-5678-9
- 01234-56-78-9
- 0123-4-5678-9
- 012-345-678-9
- 01-234567-8-9
- 01-234-5678-9
- 0-12345-678-9
- 0-123-45678-9
- 0-123-45678-9
- 01-23456-78-9
- 0-123456-78-9
- 0-1234567-8-9

No Match:

- 01-234-56789-0
- 01-234-567-8
- 01--2345678-9
- 01-2345678--9
- 0-1-23456789
- -01-2345678-9

For now, I could not quite figure out how to match the 2 'in-between' hyphens: `^\d\d{7}\d-\d$`

EDIT:
Thanks to the answers I had to this question, I was able to expand it to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925071/regex-to-extend-isbn-10-and-isbn-13-to-non-english-speaking-countries?noredirect=1#comment116560684_65925071) regarding ISBN-10 and ISBN-13...

Comment: Why is `0-1-2345678-9` not valid?

Comment: My mistake, just corrected...

Comment: @YaasineDM I rolled back your edits. New questions get new posts. You can't go back changing your OP with different conditions that would invalidate given answers. So, feel free to open a new post.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, I was wondering how to do it... I just posted a new question following your advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65925071/regex-to-extend-isbn-10-and-isbn-13-to-non-english-speaking-countries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents:

```
^(?=.{11}-\d$)(?:\d+-){3}\d
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlXXDs/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

  - `.{11}-\d$` - Any character other than newline 11 times followed by a hypen, a single digit and the end string anchor.
  - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\d+-` - 1+ digit followed by an hyphen.
  - `){3}` - Close non-capture group and match three times.
- `\d` - Match a single digit.

I guess alternatively even `^(?=.{13}$)(?:\d+-){3}\d$` would work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which seems even simpler... I tried to adapt it to match an ISBN-10 or 13 for non-English speaking areas:`/^((97(8|9))*\d{9}|(97(8|9)-)*(?=.{11}-)(?:\d+-){3}|(97(8|9) )*(?=.{11} )(?:\d+ ){3})[\dx]$/i`; matching 9780123456789, 979-01-234-5678-x, and 0123 4 5678 9. Do you think it could be further simplified?

Comment: Then I think you can make it `^(?=.{13}$)(?:\d+-){3}\d$` nice ++

Comment: I had that as an alternative at the last line @TheFourthBird, but I wasn't sure which one would be the "better" one. Thanks for the Kudos =)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I will update my question accordingly (with the right examples) but basically: optional (ISBN-13) `978` or `979` prefix, followed by 10 digits (ISBN-10), last one potentially an `x`, with variants including hyphens or spaces with the same constraints as previously mentioned...

Answer (score 4):

You can assert 7 digits and the `digit - digit` part at the end.

For the match there should be at least a single digit before and after the hyphen to prevent consecutive hyphens.

`^\d(?=(?:-?\d){7}-?\d-\d$)\d*-\d+-\d*\d-\d$`

- `^` Start of string
- `\d` Match a single digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:-?\d){7}` Match 7 digits separated by an optional `-`
  - `-?\d-\d$` Match an optional `-` and the `\d-\d$` at the end
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\d*-\d+-\d*\d-\d` Match possible formats where all hyphens are separated by at least a single digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZCfou/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I would need to look further into Positive lookahead... You were of a great help...

Comment: By the way, I also used this to match an ISBN-10 or 13 for non-English speaking areas: `^((97(8|9))*\d{9}|^(97(8|9)-)*(\d(?=(?:-?\d){7}-?\d-)\d*-\d+-\d*\d-)|^(97(8|9) )*(\d(?=(?: ?\d){7} ?\d )\d* \d+ \d*\d ))[\dx]$`; matching `9780123456789`, `979-01-234-5678-x`, and `0123 4 5678 9`. Do you think it could be further simplified?