# Regex to extend ISBN-10 and ISBN-13 to non-English speaking countries

Tags: regex

I am looking for a Regex to match a string which should:

- start with an optional `978-` or `979-` prefix
- continue with a digit
- have a permutation of exactly 7 digits and 2 hyphens, without 2 consecutive hyphens
- end with a sequence of digit, hyphen, digit (which can be an `x`)

NB.: Hyphens can be replaced (coherently) by spaces or not present altogether...

Match:

- 9780309091695
- 0309091695
- 979030909169x
- 030909169x
- 978-0-309-09169-5
- 1-84356-028-3
- 978 0 8044 2957 7
- 93 86954 21 4
- 979-0-943396-04-2
- 0-9752298-0-X
- 979 99921 58 10 0
- 80 902734 1 x
- 979-9971-5-0210-X
- 978-425-059-0
- 979 85 359 0277 x

No Match:

- 978030909169
- 97803090916951
- 030909169
- 03090916951
- 978-0--30909169-5
- `978 0  30909169 5`
- 978 0-309 09169-5
- 978-0-309-091695-
- -1-84356-028-3
- 978-0309091695
- 978-0-30909169-5
- 1-843-56-028-3

My current proposition is thanks to answers I had to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922591/regex-for-a-permutation-of-exactly-7-digits-and-2-hyphens-without-2-consecutive) and should be able to be further simplified: `/^((97(8|9))*\d{9}|(97(8|9)-)*(?=.{11}-)(?:\d+-){3}|(97(8|9) )*(?=.{11} )(?:\d+ ){3})[\dx]$/i`

Comment: Why do you use the `i` modifier in a regexp that doesn't match any letters?

Comment: What do you mean by "coherently"? If they use a hyphen as a separator in one place, they can't use a space later?

Comment: Yes, either they use only hyphens, spaces or none...

Comment: Use a capture group to match the first optional hyphen/space, and then use a back-reference in the later places to require the same separator to be used.

Comment: the i is for the last `x` which could also be an `X`...

Comment: I tried to come up with an answer, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do "permutation of exactly 7 digits and 2 hyphens, without 2 consecutive hyphens". Disallowing 2 consecutive hyphens can probably be done with a negative lookahead, but I'm not sure how to combine that with the permutation and limit the total number of hyphens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
^(?![- ])(?:(?:97[89])?([- ]?)(?=(?:\d\1?){9}\1[\dxX]$)(?:\d+\1){3}[\dxX]|(?=.{11}([- ])[\dxX]$)(?:\d+\2){3}[\dxX])
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JiQKSS/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?![- ])` - Negative lookahead to prevent a leading hyphen or space.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `97[89]` - Match "97"  followed by either an 8 or 9.
    - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `(` - Open 1st capture group:

    - `[- ]?` - Optionally match an hyphen or space.
    - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
  - `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

    - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

      - `\d\1?` - Capture a digit and optionally match what is captured in the 1st capture group.
      - `){9}` - Close the non-capture group and match it nine times (to assert a position with 9 digits ahead).
    - `\1[\dxX]$` - Again match what is captured in the 1st capture group followed by a digit or lower- or uppercase "x" and the end string anchor.
    - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `\d+\1` - 1+ digits followed by what is captured in the 1st capture group.
    - `){3}` - Close the non-capture group and match it three times.
  - `[\dxX]` - Match a digit, a lower- or uppercase "x".
  - `|` - Or:
  - `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

    - `.{11}` - Match eleven characters other than newline.
    - `([- ])` - OA 2nd capture group to match either hypen or space.
    - `[\dxX]$` - Match a digit, a lower- or uppercase "x" up to end string anchor.
    - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
  - `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `\d+\2` - Match 1+ digits and what is captured in the 2nd capture group.
    - `){3}` - Close non-capture group and match three times.
  - `[\dxX]$` - Match a digit, a lower- or uppercase "x".
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.

Comment: Thank your for this second proposition which works indeed. However, it seems to be more complicated than I anticipated, even compared to `/^((97[89])*\d{9}|(97[89]-)*(?=.{11}-)(?:\d+-){3}|(97[89] )*(?=.{11} )(?:\d+ ){3})[\dxX]$/` which has a redundant `(97[89] )*` group (but avoids to check for a leading hyphen or space)...

Answer (score 1):

This value is at both match and not match `978 0 309 09169 5`. I think it should be matched as it has the same prefix, 10 digits and same amount of delimiters.

Another option could be matching an optional prefix and either 10 digits or the part with the delimiters using an alternation `|`

You could capture an optional space or hyphen in group 1 using `([- ])?` and refer to it using a backreference `\1` to keep the delimiters consistent.

```
^(?:97[89]([- ])?)?(?:\d{10}|(?=(?:\d\1?){9}\1?[xX\d]$)\d+(?:\1?\d+){2}\1?[\dxX])$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of sting
- `(?:97[89]([- ])?)?` Optionally match the prefix and capture optional hyphen in **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{10}` Match 10 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?=(?:\d\1?){9}\1?[xX\d]$)` Positive lookahead, assert 9 digits followed by an optional delimiter and either `x` `X` or a digit till the end of the string
  - `\d+(?:\1?\d+){2}` Match 1+ digits and repeat 2 times matching an optional delimiter and 1+ digits
  - `-?[\dxX]` Match optional `-` and either `x` `X` or a digit
- `)`  Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RAijoP/1)

Comment: I also was confused by the sample data but noticed a similar sample "978 0 309 09169 5" and OP's comment saying *"NB.: Hyphens can be replaced (coherently) by spaces or not present altogether..."*. Nonetheless nicely done (again) =)

Comment: @JvdV I missed the last sentence `Hyphens can be replaced (coherently) by spaces or not present altogether` Doh!

Comment: It's easy to miss and to be fair, the sample data has got a flaw that may throw readers off =)

Comment: Just figured out both our answered don't take into account the possibility of something like 0-345-78673-9.....I guess OP Just needs to show it's a possibility but it probably is because of the optional prefix. Anyways I'll call it a day and I'll see in the morning.

Comment: @JvdV You're right, the sample is `978 0 309 09169 5` is an oversight (should have tested double spaces). I added other examples to take into account ISBN-10 with hyphens or spaces which are not captured indeed with both propositions...